# pyplot imshow() does work but not in a virtual environment(No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package), how to fix it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

in my ubuntu 16.04 system, pyplot imshow() used to work fine both in system python and in a virtual environment (for tensorflow). If file aa.py contains lines below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
p.plot(range(20),range(20))
p.show()
```

when I run `python aa.py` it runs ok. (I see a graph). but when I activate a virtual environment and run `python aa.py` in it, I see errors below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as p
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 62, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import tkagg  # Paint image to Tk photo blitter extension.
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 5, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/home/ckim/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package
```

I think I have solved this one before but forget how I did it.

Comment: maybe when I made the virtual environment, I missed the --system-site-packages option?

Comment: Most likely your virtual environment has no GUI (at least I found that out when I tried to run Ubuntu on a win10 VE). There are workarounds but it is not straightforward.

Comment: @BrunoVermeulen hi, thanks. Probably the backend was not working. I just made a new virtual environment and installed tensorflow 2.0 and the matplotlib works now. I don't know what has happened before.  (and there was a line `matplotlib.use('agg')` by mistake. In the new virtual environment, I had to comment this line out. and the old virtual environment didn't work even without this line.)

Comment: Excellent. May I ask on what system you installed the VE?

Comment: It is ubuntu 16.04.6.